# Dynamically setting an object field value in Apex

Tags: apex

*I have searched and read through countless questions & answers here, scoured the interwebs, etc. and I cannot find out whether what I want to do is even doable, much less how.  I don't know if I am searching for the wrong terms, looking past the answer, or just being stupid.  (FYI: After being a developer on a different large on-premise CRM for almost 5 years, I am only approximately 8 months new to Salesforce; so go easy, please, if I am being stupid.)*

### Prelude

I have found countless ways to **get** the value of an sObjectField using a variable.  E.g.,

```
Account a = new Account(Name = 'Test Account');
String n = 'Name';
String result = a.get(n);

// result == 'Test Account'
```

This can obviously be "genericized" using objects, lists, maps and whatnot; and then with `for` loops or other iteration, one could **get** multiple field values when the field names were not previously known.

---

## Question

#### Can you do something similar to *set* a field value using a variable for the field name?

---

### What I've Tried

```
a.n = 'New Account Name';

// Results in "Variable does not exist: n" error.
```

```
a.set(n) = 'New Account Name';
a.get(n) = 'New Account Name';
a.(a.get(n)) = 'New Account Name';
(sObjectField) a.n = 'New Account Name';
(sObjectField) a.get(n) = 'New Account Name';

// All result in "Expression cannot be assigned" error.
```

I've used `Schema.SObjectType.Account.fields.getMap()` and tried all sorts of permutations and combinations of things.  (I didn't record all that I tried because I tried hacking at it over and over and can't remember everything.)

I've individually tried...

```
sObjectField n = Account.Name;
                 Account.Name.getDescribe();
                 Account.Name.getDescribe().getName();
                 Account.Name.getDescribe().getsObjectField();
```

... all followed by `a.n = 'New Account Name';`

(which honestly wouldn't really help since the `Name` part of those would also need to be a variable for it work in a real use case).

And all sorts of things with `()`, `{}`, and `[]` that obviously didn't work.

---

### Use Case

In a test data factory class I was wanting to iterate a map that has field names and values (where the field names could be different every time) and then create an object with those field names and values.  If I can't use a variable to set a field name, I'm going to have to go through and check every possible field name.  That obviously makes for MUCH more code; and if we ever add new fields to that object and would want to be able to set those in a test, we would have to add those fields to this code.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `put(key,value)` method on `SObject` does what you're looking for. Slightly modified example from the [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_put):

```
String fieldName = 'description';
Account acc = new Account(name = 'test', description = 'old desc');
String oldDesc = (String)acc.put(fieldName, 'new desc');
System.assertEquals('old desc', oldDesc);
System.assertEquals('new desc', acc.description);
```

Comment: That worked like a charm - thank you so much!

Now I _do_ feel stupid!

Even though I didn't explicitly list it in my **What I've Tried**, I really thought that I had tried that.  As I stated, I was hacking through a lot of different attempts; when I moved into an Execute Anonymous Apex window in Developer Console so that I could hack through them quicker, I lost track of everything that I had tried.

I will now be able to make my trigger helper code MUCH more elegant, and make an even more useful test data factory.  Thanks to you, I might be the (temporary) star of our small dev team!

Comment: @Moonpie Test factory frameworks already exist: [one](https://github.com/dhoechst/Salesforce-Test-Factory) [two](https://github.com/mbotos/SmartFactory-for-Force.com). There are more, these are mentioned often.