# How to dynamically reference custom field?

Tags: apex, dynamic

I am new to Salesforce, and programming.
Is there a way to reference CustomObject__c when adding to list, without hardcoding the name of the field (customObject__c)?
Example:

> ```
> If(Name ='123'){
> updateListOpp.add(new Opportunity(customObject__c = null);
> }
> ```

I have multiple custom objects that need to be added to a list, So I just wanted to know if there is a better way, instead of having to hardcode each custom object and having multiple conditional statements.

Comment: There's a bunch of questions covering this.  These questions I quickly found, there's heaps more on here as well.  https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/324336/reference-sobject-fields-dynamically-from-a-string-value   https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/305507/dynamically-setting-an-object-field-value-in-apex ?  If not, can you edit your question to provide more information and why the other questions on here don't cover what you're after.

Comment: Nick, thank you for the links. Basically, I was having issues referencing when trying to add the custom field to a list. This is why other questions are not covering what I'm after.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SObject behaves like a map, meaning you can use `.put()` method like this.

```
List<SObject> sObjects = new List<SObject>();

Opportunity o = new Opportunity();
o.put('Name', 'asd');
sObjects.add(o);

Lead l = new Lead();
l.put('Email', 'asd@asd.asd');
sObjects.add(l);

System.debug(sObjects);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have accepted your answer and help @damecek